# User level permissions inside OAuth API paradigm

Tags: oauth, permissions

Looking at some existing implementations out there, I've already seen 2 ways to go about *scope* in an OAuth API. One way is to associate permissions with an application at time of registration. Another is to pass them along with Request Tokens at runtime. The prevailing theme is that **OAuth permissions are associated with applications**.

In what I would view as **a traditional paradigm, by contrast, permissions can be associated with *users***. The idea being if UserA and UserB have different levels of access, then UserB may be granted access to features UserA may not.

My question is how is the later is typically implemented within an OAuth paradigm? Since permissions seem to typically be associate with an application instead of a user, I'm wondering how to handle user-level permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what our mobile developer said, it's pretty much like a traditional paradigm. The server includes some type of *role* attribute on each user which the app can use to expose features conditionally.